# how to get inputs from wearable devices

Tags: wear-os

I'm implementing a notification system using Xamarin platform, which extends to wearable devices to send the notification. I also want to get the input of user from the wear notification and i have programed it in such away that user can select text or use voice. i followed the following tutorial

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/voice-input.html

my code is:

```
void SendWearNotification (string message, string from)
{

    var valuesForActivity = new Bundle();
    valuesForActivity.PutString ("message", message);

     String groupkey = "group_key_emails";

    var intent = new Intent (this, typeof(MyMainActivity));
    intent.PutExtras (valuesForActivity);

    intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

    var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder (this)
        .SetAutoCancel (true)
        .SetContentIntent (pendingIntent)
        .SetContentTitle (from)
        .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.Iconlogo)
        .SetContentText (message)  //message is the one recieved from the notification
        .SetTicker(from)
        .SetGroup (groupkey)    //creates groups
        .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High);
        //

    //for viewing the message in second page

    var pagestyle= new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    pagestyle.SetBigContentTitle (from)
        .BigText (messagefromapp);    //message from app is the one rerieved from the wcf app

    //second page 
    var secondpagenotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder (this)
        .SetStyle (pagestyle)
        .Build ();


    //intent for voice input or text selection 
    var wear_intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView);
    var wear_pending_intent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this,0,wear_intent,0);



    // Create the reply action and add the remote input
    setRemoteInput ();

    var action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder (Resource.Drawable.ic_mes, 
                                           GetString (Resource.String.messages), wear_pending_intent)
        .AddRemoteInput (remoteinput)
        .Build ();

    //add it to the notification builder
    Notification notification = builder.Extend (new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender ()
        .AddPage (secondpagenotification).AddAction(action)).Build ();


    //create different notitfication id so that we can as list
    if(notification_id<9){
        notification_id += 1;
    }else{
        notification_id=0;
    }

    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
    notificationManager.Notify (notification_id+2, notification);
}
```

this method is implmented inside GCMListnerService class.

According to the tutorial from the above link, i can retreive the input data user selected or spoke uing the following code:

```
private void getResponse(Intent intent){
    Bundle remoteInput = RemoteInput.GetResultsFromIntent(intent);
    if (remoteInput != null) {
        Toast.MakeText(this, remoteInput.GetCharSequence(EXTRA_VOICE_REPLY), ToastLength.Short);
    }
    //return null;
}
```

My question is when do i call this method, how do i know if user have selected a text en send from the wearable device. if there is any event which i can use.

Comment: First, the link you tried t include in your post is not visible, so please edit and correct that. Secondly, please state your question more clearly, I am not sure there is enough info to see what you want to do, what you have done and what the issue is.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i hope its clear now what i meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. the method the gets the remote input (the "getresponse" in my case) should be called from the "Oncreate" method of an activity that is used when the notification is created. In my case the actvity i used is "MyMainActivity" when i create the intent of the notification as u can see it in the code. So this means the method will be called twice, when the application runs, and when user reponds from the wear. but ony in the second case will the "remoteinput.getResultfromIntent" will have a value. I hope it will help for someone with same issues.